# How to combine Kohana ORM validation and MySQL functions?

Tags: mysql, validation, orm, model, kohana

`test` validation will fail, because there's MySQL function `AES_ENCRYPT` etc.

**ORM with MySQL function**

```
$user = ORM::factory('user', 1);
$user->test = DB::expr("AES_ENCRYPT('something', 'secret_key')");
```

**ORM Model with validation**

```
class Model_User extends ORM {

    public function rules()
    {
        'test' => array(
            array('alpha'),
        );
    }
}
```

Only solution I could figure out, is that I remove ORM validation and validate `test` with normal Kohana validation before using `DB::expr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[External Validation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/validation) is only option.